# How can I get the globals or environment from the main state to a Lua lane?

Tags: c, multithreading, api, lua, lua-lanes

```
local lanes = require "lanes".configure()
local linda = lanes.linda()
local thread = lanes.gen({globals = _G}, function()
print("Starting thread...")
while true do
    local command = linda:receive("cmd")
    if command=="quit" then
        break
    else
        broadcast(-1,"Hello from lanes.")
    end
end
end)

local threads = {}
local NCORES = 2
for i=1,NCORES do threads[i] = thread() end
linda:send("cmd", "test")
for i=1,NCORES do linda:send("cmd", "quit") end
for i=1,NCORES do threads[i]:join() end
```

As a test on my game server to get Lua Lanes running properly, I am trying to use a global function from the main state in a new thread. Unfortunately this particular code keeps resulting in an `Assert Failure in tools.c line 1216`. I'm trying to set this up so I can do busy work without locking up the main thread, and ultimately my game server. Is there a better way to do this perhaps? Or maybe I could run my scripts via `luaL_newthread(state)` in my server? Please advise me in the right direction as this is currently halting my development. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not access globals like that in a lane. The thread is run in a separate state. What you get is a deep copy of the globals table (not a reference). Also, by calling a global function in a separate thread you are risking synchronization issues.

What you can do is to `require` a module in the thread itself. To get the `broadcast` function into the thread, you have these options:

1. Put `broadcast` and other functions into a module and call `require` in the thread.
2. <strike>Store `broadcast` as a `local` before the thread function to get it as an upvalue.</strike>

**Update**: unfortunately the second way does not work as it used to anymore. Due to compatibility issues with LuaJIT 2, Lanes has to [compute a mapping table of native functions](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes/blob/master/src/lanes.c#L2423) at the time `configure` is run. I have not found a way to transfer a simple C function into the thread other way than to actually `require` the module in the thread.

Comment: Okay then, hmm... I have all of my C functions as well as my Lua functions registered as globals. How can I go about rolling them into a module and still be able to use all of my internal C functions? i.e. `broadcast` calls to a core function that will send a packet to players. Would I lose this functionality?

Comment: If creating a module is not feasible, try adding `local broadcast = broadcast` before `lanes.gen()` (the second approach). Only the `broadcast` function will get copied to the lane.

Comment: `function broadcast not found in the destination transfer database` Is the error I keep getting when I try that. I even tried sending it via a linda object and it gives the same error. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Alright, looks like I'll have to play around with it a bit and see if I can come up with anything. Thanks for the help at the very least. If I had some sort of tutorial it might be feasible to make a module. Everything I've read makes no sense tho. If you know how or could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.